# Problem with Virtual Host in XAMPP, project based on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to start project in laravel on my lacalhost. This project is not mine, I work on it, and try to figured out how it was builded. There is main files:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV3Ka.png)

And in this files is laravel.core. He look's inside like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3TW.png)

In my XAMPP httpd-vhosts I have VirtualHost. Before every my project work fine without problem. In virtual host I create path to this main folder where the index.php is. But when in browser I try to open there is warning that this site is dangerous because it is self certificated, after that, there's only XAMPP Dashboard, nothing else.

In my index.php I have path:

`require __DIR__.'/laravel_core/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

And in above file I have:

`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Edit:

So here is .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

In index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel_core/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel_core/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

In the bottom I add code from my .env, next from bootsrap/autoload.php and in the end from vendor/autoload.php:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2OWwGrH6hL+4MKkV7sZZ21MTjSHv/zacUDC67FWVBa4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testowa1
DB_USERNAME=testowa1
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=cms_

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit7c0fb85d4a884560a3dba2e1e877f7b0::getLoader();
```

Comment: `VirtualHost` may only respond to a combination of ip and port. If it's the first time you get this alert, it's likely that you only have configured them to use port 80, but the app is redirecting to 443, so apache doesn't know what to serve. Duplicate your vhost config to use the correct port or reconfigure the app.

Comment: I tried do something with your advice. I've duplicated my vhost to the right port, but it didn.t help. Next I created my own ssl certificate, and still the same. I tried to reconfigure my app, but I don't know how exactly. In my .env file?

Comment: It's probably a Redirect, is there an `.htaccess` file? Please try to gather more info on redirects, server config, url that you are accessing and where you end up, etc. Otherwise we can only go on based on wild guesses.

Comment: I edited my question, and add some code, maybe it will help to understand where is the problem. If someone have idea what resource can I add, please write.

Comment: I still think is a `VirtualHost` issue with the port... Try removing first pair of `RewriteCond` / `RewriteRule` from `.htaccess` (the one with `%{HTTPS} !=on`).

Comment: I followed your advice and removed this two lines from .htaccess. The dashboard's view had gone but a new error shows up. I will add this error in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, This problem is solved by msg. He wrote in comment that problem is with VirtualHost, and when I removed this two mentioned lines in .htaccess, there is no more problem with showing XAMPP dashboard.